# Django url parameters in html code

Tags: python, html, django, pycharm

I am trying to pass the id of a todolist item to my html code so that everything works when I am editing the todolist item and I click submit.

**In views.py:**

```
def edit(request, id):
    todo = Todo.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {
        'todo': todo
    }

    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        title = request.POST['title']
        text = request.POST['text']

        todo.title = title


        todo.text = text

        todo.save()

        return redirect('/todos')

    else:
        return render(request, 'edit.html', context)
```

**In urls.py:**

```
url(r'^details/(?P<id>\w{0,50})/edit/$', views.edit, name='edit')
```

**In HTML:**

```
<h2>Edit Todo- {{ todo.title }}</h2>

<form action="{% url 'edit' request.todo.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<label for="title">Title</label> <br/>

<input type="text" name="title" id="title"/>
<br>

<label for="text">Text</label> <br/>
<textarea type="text" name="text" id="text"></textarea>
<br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I think the problem is in my url in the html code. I can't figure out how to pass my todolist item's id parameter.

The error I keep getting is

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Please help

Comment: Just {% url 'edit' todo.id %} in form action, or leave it blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is there:, do not use "**request**", the object sent through context is "**todo**":

```
<form action="{% url 'edit' todo.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

Or you may leave it blank. Blank means the current displayed views

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```